# Split strings or XML to send IDs to a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have an application in C#, and have to send a list of IDs (int) to my db in SQL Server to make a couple of  joins. I have the list of IDs in a Dataset on memory.

I know two ways to do it: One, is to create a string with the id's separated by pipes, and split them in sql, inserting them in a temp table. Then I can do the joins that I want.

The other way, is do "getXML" to my Dataset, and send it. Then, I can insert the info in a temp table, and do the joins that I want.

Which way is better, and why? Or another option better than both?

The number of IDs to pass are variable, using SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008, Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think XML is better because it is more robust. It is self-documenting, you don't have to worry about delimiters and you could even validate the XML coming in against an XSD. With a delimited string you would to handle it if your data contains your separator character and other vagaries. Parsing is doable but it's better to not have to reinvent the wheel, especially for something that works pretty darn well already.

Here's a [nice and tidy sample from Pinal Dave](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/13/sql-server-simple-example-of-reading-xml-file-using-t-sql/) to get you going. Your proof of concept could be even simpler.

Comment: In my work, my boss want to split, I want to use XML. I ask it to friend, and he says that xml is more difficult to check if doesn't work something, and that in older versions of sql server may not work, against split strings is easier. I preffer XML for that you say, but I don't know how to argue against my friend

Comment: Prove the concept. Create a proc that reads the XML and operates on it. The code will show that it would be a much cleaner process than parsing  text. You wouldn't even have to write C# to do that. Just create a sample XML doc in a T-SQL statement to run the test.

Comment: @ElVieejo SQL Server 6.5 (circa mid to late 90's) was the last version that had no support for XML. Are you really worried about going back that far?

Comment: don't know that!! So, my friend lie to me when he said that sql server 2005 doesn't support very well XML. Thanks! (Got to say, I can't believe that I believe him)

Comment: For INTs I agree, but for strings the XML approach is not safe (consider the case where a string contains < or &). For most cases, CLR is the fastest in the case where you can implement CLR (I realize not everyone can do this).

Comment: Phantom fears like that are fairly common in programming. The systems are complex, errors and missteps frequent and people tend to shy away from technologies because of bad experiences that may have been rooted in their own problems.

Comment: I suggest you google "t-sql split string", copy even the *least* complicated algorithm you find, and show it to your boss. He'll probably agree with your XML approach when he sees that splitting a string in T-SQL is not a trivial operation like it is in C#.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2008, there is another way: pass your ids as a [table value parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx).

Comment: is a good option, but my application is used  by two clients: one of them have sql server 2008 and the another one use sql server 2005

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Paul in that it'd be nice to use a standard format here.  Although, it'd be nicer if you could do this with a more efficient format like JSON.  JSON is smaller and typically faster to parse than XML.

It'd be best if SQL Server had native support for it.  However, that doesn't necessarily have to stop you.  If efficiency is critical, then check this out...
http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/

Comment: efficiency is not critical, it's a simple site of reporting, but it's interesting to know this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a CLR table-valued function. Shouldn't take much to [convert this function](http://dataeducation.com/sqlclr-string-splitting-part-2-even-faster-even-more-scalable/) to handle integers instead.

Then you can just say:

```
SELECT t.Columns
  FROM dbo.YourTable AS t
  INNER JOIN dbo.CLRFunctionName(@IntegerList) AS f
  ON t.ColumnName = f.Item;
```

For XML (in the case where you can't implement CLR), you can do this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitInts]
(
   @List       VARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
   RETURN ( SELECT Item FROM ( SELECT Item = x.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'int') FROM 
            ( SELECT [XML] = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
              + '</i>').query('.') ) AS a CROSS APPLY [XML].nodes('i') AS x(i)
          ) AS y WHERE Item IS NOT NULL
   );
GO
```

And do the same thing...

```
SELECT t.Columns
  FROM dbo.YourTable AS t
  INNER JOIN dbo.SplitInts(@IntegerList) AS f
  ON t.ColumnName = f.Item;
```

In both cases, no temp tables or table variables required.